# Finding Orthogonal Complements of Subsets of $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, orthogonality

> find the orthogonal complements of the following subsets of $\ell^2$:

> a) $\{\delta_k\}_{k \in J}$, where $J \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

> b) $c_{00}$ (the subspace of sequences with only finitely many
> nonzero terms).

> c) $\{\delta_k + \delta_{k+1}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$

My attempt:

a) Intuitively I believe this should be all sequences with a zero in position $k$ and any value everywhere else. But Im not sure what the proper notation is for such a sequence.

b) Unsure

c) Zeros in position $k$ and $k+1$ and any value in the other positions. Again unsure about notation.

Comment: I would denote a) by $\text{span} \left \{ \delta_k \right \}_{k\notin J}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $\{(a_n):a_j=0 \, \forall j \in J\}$.

b) $c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell^{2}$ and so its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$, the set which consists of only the 'zero sequence'.

c) Your answer is wrong. The correct answer is $\{(a_n): a_k+a_{k+1}=0 \, \forall k\}$ But this, together with the condition $\sum |a_k|^{2} <\infty$ shows that the answer is again $\{0\}$. [I am assuming that $k$ is a variable in c)].

If $k$ is fixed in c) then the answer would be $\{(a_n): a_{k+1}=-a_k\}$.

Comment: My bad I updated $c)$ so it should be more clear now. I assume $k \in \mathbb{N}$ means $k$ is fixed? Also is it a general property that any dense sequence only has the trivial orthogonal complement?

Comment: Yes, that is true in any Hilbert space. @Pame